# Setting Request Time Limit in Drupal

Tags: web-services, drupal, asihttprequest

Anyone knows how to up the request time length in drupal? I'm trying to download large files via the web services module but my token keeps expiring because the request takes so long. I know there is a setting in drupal to do this but I just can't find it.

UPDATE

So I found out how to up the request time (/admin/build/services/settings) but that didn't work. I'm still getting "The request timed out" on files about 10mb large. Anyone has any ideas? Also, I'm using ASIHTTPRequest and drupal-ios-sdk and downloading the files to an iPad.

Comment: Have you tried using `ini_set()`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Possibly `max_execution_time` or `max_inputtime` settings could work for you.

Comment: Thanks, turned out the issue was on the ipad side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the default timeOutSeconds property on the ASIHTTPRequest was too small (10 seconds). When I uped it, my large files downloaded ok